# How to create database and tables in Bluemix DB2 cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am new of the bluemix DB2 cloud database, I have to create database and table's. Kindly some one advice me how to create it.

1. how to create database and table
2. how to access the database in external
3. how to create service credentials
4. how to find the url and port,database

[image]

Comment: Hi Karthik, welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question is too broad for stackoverflow and will probably get closed. Have a look at the help section for tips on asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this the db2 service you are looking for help with: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-db2-on-cloud?